# FormFields for (Admin)Inlines || Can't import InlineModelAdmin

Tags: python, django

I want to catch up some extra information within my Django Admin through some extra Fields. I want to use inlines for that purpose.

I have:

```
class YourModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    slot_count_request = forms.IntegerField(label='#-slot-size', initial=4 )

class Card_Group_proxy_inline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SomeRandomModel
    form = YourModelForm
```

This works fine for if I want to use a model within. I thought I can get rid of it, if I inherit from `admin.InlineModelAdmin`, but then I get an error:

```
AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.admin' has no attribute 'InlineModelAdmin'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `InlineModelAdmin` class can be imported with:

```
from django.contrib.admin.options import InlineModelAdmin
```

However, I have not seen `InlineModelAdmin` used directly before. Usually, you would use `admin.TabularInline` or `admin.StackedInline`.

Comment: Works, but I still need to declare a model on it. I also get an admin.E105 error for if I inherit my inline from `InlineModelAdmin`. Any Ideas on it? (Sry for I asked my Question somewhat explorative.)

Comment: As I said, Django does not expect you to inherit `InlineModelAdmin` directly, so I don't have any advice about trying to do that. Since an inline is meant to show a related model, it's not surprising that you have to declare a model.